# How to count number of elements in array without using method .length

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, count, counter

function addValue(arr, value){

arr.push(value)

return ...

}

console.log(addValue([1, 2, 3], 10)); // 4 without using .length

Comment: Please include a question in the body of your post, and always properly format code. More information on formatting is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array.

```js
function addValue(arr, value) {
    return arr.push(value);
}

console.log(addValue([1, 2, 3], 10)); // 4 without using .length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pure javascript return length of the array without .length

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];

function arrayLength(a){
  var length = 0;
  while(a[length]!==undefined){
    length++;
  }
  return length;
}

console.log(arrayLength(a));       // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addValue(arr, value){

arr.push(value)
var count=0;
arr.forEach(a=>{
count++;})
return count

}

console.log(addValue([1, 2, 3], 10));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use .length, then you can make your own length variable by manually counting them

```
function addValue(arr, value){

    arr.push(value)

    return ( ()=> {
         var mylength=0
         for(var k in a) mylength+=1
         return mylength
    } )()

}
```

Although I'm guessing the reason you don't want to use .length is simply because your using some kind of sudo-array that doesn't have a length property, in which case you can just convert it to an array

```
....
return Array.apply(null, ar).length
```

If not though length is pretty much what you want

Another option, again, as shorthand for counting the elements, is to just the length of a list of the keys

```
return Object.keys(ar).length
```

Or Object.values

```
return Object.values(ar).length
```

Or Object.entries

```
return Object.entries(ar).length
```

(Usually these methods are good for sudo-array or custom arrays made from scratch that don't have a length property)

Or just return the push function

```
return ar.push(value)
```